# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "setTokenURI" ? even i use ^0.6.0 version

Tags: solidity, python

When I was trying to mint an NFT then, I ran my script it gave me error:

`DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "setTokenURI"?         _setTokenURI(tokenId, _tokenURI);`

I know `_setTokenURI` was gone with solidity version ^0.8.0 but I am using ^0.6.0

### `AdvancedCollectible.sol:`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract AdvancedCollectible is ERC721, VRFConsumerBase{
    uint256 public tokenCounter;
    bytes32 public keyhash;
    uint256 public fee;
    enum Breed{CAT1, CAT2, NFT1, NFT2}
    mapping(uint256 => Breed) public tokenIdToBreed;
    mapping(bytes32 => address) public requestIdToSender;
    event requestedCollectible(bytes32 indexed requestId, address requester);
    event breedAssigned(uint256 indexed tokenId, Breed breed);

    constructor(address _vrfCoordinator, address _linkToken, bytes32 _keyhash, uint256 _fee) public
    VRFConsumerBase(_vrfCoordinator, _linkToken)
    ERC721("Dogie", "NFT")
    {
        tokenCounter = 0;
        keyhash = _keyhash;
        fee = _fee;
    }
    // vrf takes too many time. kal ake do contract verification to see the token id.
    function createCollectible() public returns (bytes32){
        bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyhash, fee);
        requestIdToSender[requestId] = msg.sender;
        emit requestedCollectible(requestId, msg.sender);
        // tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 2;
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomNumber) internal override {
        Breed breed = Breed(randomNumber % 4);
        uint256 newTokenId = tokenCounter;
        tokenIdToBreed[newTokenId] = breed;
        emit breedAssigned(newTokenId, breed);
        address owner = requestIdToSender[requestId];
        _safeMint(owner, newTokenId);
        tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
        
    }

    function setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) public {
        // 11:10:43 / 16:22:11   
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: caller is not owner no approved");
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, _tokenURI);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share all your smart contract code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.